# Zpanel subdomains not working with www

Tags: centos, subdomain

Hello I have server with Centos 6.5 64bit Final i have noticed that my subdomains does not work properly for example if i create subdomain: **example.domain.com** everything is fine you can type that in your browser and it will work but if somebody will type **www.example.domain.com** it will fail to open instead of subdomain content that i have created it will open zpanelcp login page.

So my question is what i should do in order to get this working is it domain fault or is it server fault and i need something to fix in actual server?

Answer (score 0):

to create a sub-domain on zPanel just follow this steps :

1. Login to ZPanel as user
2. Click "Sub Domains"
3. Enter sub-domain prefix and select the domain
4. Use create new home directory
5. Click "Create"
6. Now go to your domain dns manager not zPanel dns manager "ex : godaddy ..."
7. Under A (HOST) You will need to add new record for the prefix of your sub domain with your server ip address
8. Then click "Save Changes"

your dns resolution my take some time to reflect your changes

good luck.